# WPF: how to set a property only on selecteditem not for item source

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a listview with Combobox in it:

```
<ListView x:Name="DiscountListView" Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DiscountMatrix.RelatedDiscounts}"
                      Margin="0, 7, 0, 0"
                      Style="{StaticResource AppTransparentListViewStyle}">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn
                            Width="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , AncestorType=ListView, AncestorLevel=1},Path=ActualWidth}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <ItemContainerTemplate>

                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-7, 14, 0, 0"
                                          Width="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor , AncestorType=ListViewItem, AncestorLevel=1},Path=ActualWidth}">
                                        <Border BorderBrush ="{Binding SelectedDiscount.IsNotRelated, Converter={StaticResource DisablingBoolToColorConverter}}"  BorderThickness="2" Margin="4, 0, 15, 0">

                                            <customComboBox:CustomComboBox x:Name="DiscountView" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                                           Margin="0, 8, 5, 0"
                                                                           Text="{Binding SelectedDiscount.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                           SelectedValue ="{Binding SelectedDiscount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                                                <customComboBox:CustomComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                                    <CompositeCollection>
                                                        <ComboBoxItem
                                                            Content="{DynamicResource lang_Common_SelectItem}"
                                                            IsEnabled="False" />
                                                        <CollectionContainer 
                                                            Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Discounts}}" />
                                                    </CompositeCollection>
                                                </customComboBox:CustomComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                            </customComboBox:CustomComboBox>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>

                                </ItemContainerTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

According to my logic RelatedDiscounts (actually my listview) is a list of SelectedDiscounts. I can add a discount and it will be set as SelectedItem in my Combobox (for this I should ovverride Equals in SelectedDiscount class). Every discount has IsNotRelated property (true/false depending on logic). I faced with a problem: f.e. my first list item SelectedDiscount was set as a SelectedItem in the first Combobox and it's IsNotRelated property is false by logic. Then I add the same item as SelectedItem to my second Combobox but IsNotRelated property is true. In this case first SelectedDiscount's property IsNotRelated becomes also true but should stay false. I know it's because the second time I set true for SelectedDiscount property from ItemSourse of all my Comboboxes. My question is: how can I set property only for SelectedItem of current Combobox but not for this item in ItemSourse at all? Any ideas how can I avoid standart behavior of Combobox and sorry for my English.

Here is a part of SelectedDiscount's type (DiscountModel):

```
public bool _isNotRelated;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public bool IsNotRelated
        {
            get { return _isNotRelated; }
            set
            {
                _isNotRelated = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsNotRelated");
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as DiscountModel;
            return (Id == other?.Id);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies if I am misunderstanding your issue...

The reason you are most likely seeing this is because the object `SelectedDiscount` you are binding each `ComboBox` to is the same **mutable** object. Though the object is listed in separate collections, it is the same object in memory. The collection is simply holding a **reference** to the `SelectedDiscount` objects in memory, not the object itself.

For example:

```cs
var list1 = new List<SelectedDiscount>();
var list2 = new List<SelectedDiscount>();

SelectedDiscount sd = new SelectedDiscount();

list1.Add(sd);
list2.Add(sd);

//Change Collection 1
list1[0].IsNotRelated = true;

//Both collections return true
Console.WriteLine(list1[0].IsNotRelated); //True;
Console.WriteLine(list2[0].IsNotRelated); //True;
```

You won't see this problem **immutable** objects such as `string` as they cannot change. Each collection will build it's own version of the object, not a reference like with a **mutable** object.

Essentially, you will need to create a new instance of the `SelectedDiscount` object in memory to modify one without the other being modified.

One way to do this is by implementing `ICloneable`onto your class.

```cs
public class SelectedDiscount : ICloneable
{
     [JsonIgnore]
     public bool IsNotRelated
     {
         get { return _isNotRelated; }
         set
         {
             _isNotRelated = value;
             RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsNotRelated");
         }
      }

      public object Clone()
      {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
      }
}
```

Now you can clone the object into the new collection.

```cs
var list1 = new List<SelectedDiscount>();
var list2 = new List<SelectedDiscount>();

//Assuming the IsNotRelated property is defaulted to false.
SelectedDiscount sd = new SelectedDiscount();

list1.Add(sd);
list2.Add((SelectedDiscount)sd.Clone());

//Change Collection 1
list1[0].IsNotRelated = true;

//Only the first collection will return true
Console.WriteLine(list1[0].IsNotRelated); //True;
Console.WriteLine(list2[0].IsNotRelated); //False;
```

You may also implement you own ways to clone as sometimes `ICloneable` may not work depending on class structure. I simply wanted to give you an example, but now that you know WHY it's behaving the way it is, you can address the issue.

Best Wishes!